# simulate onOptionsItemSelected inside method call

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar, android-menu

I have an ImageView inside a xml layout. The ImageView has an onClick method.

```
android:onClick="onHomeClicked"
```

When the user clicks my image, I want that to in turn call `onOptionsItemSelected` inside the activity. How would I do that?

The following code gives null for `homeMenuItem`:

```
MenuItem homeMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    homeMenuItem = menu.findItem(android.R.id.home);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

public void onHomeClicked(View view) {
    onOptionsItemSelected(homeMenuItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no `MenuItem`, whatever logic `onOptionsItemSelected()` would contain would fail (assuming there are multiple options).

Since you seem to have a need for shared code, move that piece of logic to its own method, then call that method from both `onHomeClicked()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Eg

```
private void mySharedMethod (){
 //implementation
}

public void onHomeClicked (View v){
  mySharedMethod();
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
  switch (item.getItemId ()){
    case android.R.id.home:
       mySharedMethod();
       return true;
    default:
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected (item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible you have to declare method and call it from `onOptionsItemSelected` and from `onHomeClicked`

```
    onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.btn:
           youNewMethod();
        break;
        }
    }

    public void onHomeClicked() {
        youNewMethod();
    }

    private void youNewMethod(){
        // write your code here
    }
```